# no run method with httpPost

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with MVC application, the browser is not able to send POST data to the controller method.
I did a test with the parameter "GET" - parameter is passed.
"POST" - nothing happens is NOK.
What to do to POST work?

```
var save = function()
{
   var data = document.getElementById('tarea').innerHTML;
   data = JSON.stringify("PiotrDusiskissssssssssssss");
   // da = JSON.stringify(da);
    //debugger;
   console.log(data);
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       timeout: 3000, // sets timeout to 3 seconds
       url: 'http://localhost:62658/Home/SaveEntry',
       dataType: "json",
       data: {'data':"sdfsdfsdfsdfsd"},
       contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
       success: function (result) {
           console.log('success');
           alert("We returned:" + result);
       },
       failure: function (e) {
           console.log('problem');
           alert(e);
       }
   });      
};
```

Problem:  method is not fired when I use  [HttpPost]
method is run for [HttpGet]

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public JsonResult SaveEntry(string data)
{   
    string wynik;
    string sqlQuery =...
```

Comment: You need to remove `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` (your not stringifying the data that your posting). And not related, but never hard code you url like that - use `url: '@Url.Action("SaveEntry", "Home")',`

Answer (score 0):

You specified `type:'POST'` it should be

```
$.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    //...
})
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped me very much.

Comment: How to understand? This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
}); on main jquery page: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ they use "type" not method.....

Comment: `type` is an alias for `method`. This has nothing to do with the issue.